# How to read a .sav file sent to the Django POST request

Tags: python, django

I am using Django to read a file that was passed in the POST request. However, when I do *pyreadstat.read_sav(file)*, I get *TypeError: Argument 'filename_path' has incorrect type (expected str, got InMemoryUploadedFile)*

I could first store in Django’s default_storage and read as pyreadstat.read_sav(file_url_in_default_storage) but is there a way to do this without storing in the default storage?

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a more elegant solution and instead solved by creating a temporary file as documented at https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.mkstemp

```
temp_file, temp_file_path = tempfile.mkstemp()  
for chunk in file.chunks():
    os.write(temp_file, chunk)
df, sav_file_meta_data = pyreadstat.read_sav(temp_file_path)
os.remove(temp_file_path)  # removing temporary file
```